# uncaught error:invalid address

Tags: truffle, react

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (formatters.js:271)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (formatters.js:97)
    at method.js:89
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Method.formatInput (method.js:88)
    at Method.toPayload (method.js:114)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (method.js:139)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (function.js:136)
    at SolidityFunction.execute (function.js:219)
    at contract.js:188
```

code reference:https://github.com/dappuniversity/ipfs_image_uploader

Script.js

this is the script to get account

```
 this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
     simpleStorage.deployed().then((instance) => {
        this.simpleStorageInstance = instance
        this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })
        // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
        return this.simpleStorageInstance.get.call(accounts[0]);

      }).then((ipfsHash) => {
        // Update state with the result.
        return this.setState({ ipfsHash })
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: can anyone clear this

Comment: sorry, I am new here and also to the technology.I am actually unable to understand the error.

Comment: Well what did you do to make it happen? What code are you running? What platform are you using?

Comment: i have provided the code reference above. I think the issue is in web3. The main code is in the src folder ...App.js

Comment: are you using Metamask or Ganache or Infura?

Comment: i am using Ganache and infura for ipfs